# Rich parse messages with push notifications service

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using [Parse](http://parse.com) service in an application I'm developing, push notifications are now working, I can send perfectly ...

But I want to implement some actions in determidos cases example: Send url to be opened as soon as the user clicks on the notification, make a call, open the map with a planned route, and more.

I wonder if this is possible, and if we had someone who already knows the way I should go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly send additional information to trigger an event inside your app, such as url opens, opening maps, etc.

First, you need to send a payload with your push notification that tells the app what to do. You can learn about that here:

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options/Android

Second, you need to create a handler inside your Android app that recognizes your push payload and knows what to do with it. You can find the appropriate start under "Responding with a Custom Activity" here:

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/Android